# How to disable nth level node if any (n-1)th node is selected in jsTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Hi am using **jsTree** and created the below shown Tree

[image]

Now i want to disable **n** th node if **(n-1**) th node is selected,ie user cant able to select different level of nodes.

eg:

1. if user selected Koramangala,then infosys,Accenture,TCS,IBM,Wipro and their child nodes should be disable
2. If Bangalore is selected,Koramangala,electronicCity,WhiteField,Marathahally and their child should be disabled and disable same level childs in US& UK

Is it possible to achieve this requirement ????

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an attribute added by jsTree to all `li` elements - the `aria-level` attribute. It starts from 1 for root element and spans whole tree showing level for every node.

You will have to do this:

1. add some events to jsTree object - `changed` event to disable visible nodes from next level and below and `open_node` to update status of to-be disabled nodes previously hidden (non-existent in the DOM till this moment to be exact)
2. add `conditionalselect` plugin to disallow node selection if node is disabled

I kept the currently selected level in var `currentlevel`. You should check that it is kept local. Also you can surely optimize the code so it wouldn't repeat enable/disable functionality.

Check demo - [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/31pacwaw/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply brother. The sample you provided is almost what i need. Here at a time one child node is selectable. But i my case, i need to select multiple nodes of same level(it can be from any parent node,but it should be of same level)

Comment: You are welcome! With multiple checkboxes you will need to provide some extra handling for different situations in select/deselect events. E.g. when one of higher level checked nodes gets unchecked - don't enable children if at least one higher level stays checked. Or when you check a higher level node - don't just disable children but also uncheck them if they were previously checked (you surely know how to enable multiselection - add `"multiple": true` in the `core` section of jsTree config).

Comment: Thanks brother. Need one more help.  i.e.. if first I selected nth child node and after that am selecting (n-1)th node. Then I need to de-select all nth level nodes. How can I achieve this requirement.

Comment: my latest code will be available here http://jsfiddle.net/thejustv2013/fxpatbp5/2/

Comment: You can't use `x:y` format for id - those are ordinary html id's. So I fixed that. Also I fixed some select/deselect stuff. See http://jsfiddle.net/fxpatbp5/3/.  I've fixed your earlier fiddle.

Comment: @NikolayErmakov: this fiddle `jsfiddle.net/fxpatbp5/3` works fine as long as all the nodes are expended. assume you select a node at level three and then you collapse the node at level three and then you select a node at level 1, it system does not unselects level 3 node and nodes at level 1 and 3 remains selected

Comment: @SharpCoder - can you check the answer below if it solves this issue

Comment: @NikolayErmakov: Did you mean the answer posted by @thejustv? his fiddle link `http://jsfiddle.net/fxpatbp5/6/` also have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the above mentioned requiremnt will be available [here in jsFfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxpatbp5/6/)

Here am listing the features

- At a time,only same level of nodes can be selectable
- If select nth level node,then all lower level nodes will be disabled
- If select nth level node and after that if select any higher level node is selected,then all lower level nodes selection will be removed

Here am adding the jquery code

```
var data = [{"id":"1","text":"India","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"#", "state": { "opened":true } },{"id":"1-1","text":"Banglore", "state": { "opened":true }, "parent":"1"},{"id":"1-1-1","text":"Koramangala","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1-1"},{"id":"1-1-1-1","text":"Infosys   ","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1-1-1"},{"id":"1-1-1-1-1","text":"D","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1-1-1-1"},{"id":"1-1-1-1-2","text":"E","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1-1-1-1"},{"id":"1-1-1-1-3","text":"G","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1-1-1-1"},{"id":"1-1-1-3","text":"Accenture ","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1-1-1"},{"id":"1-1-1-3-8","text":"C","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1-1-1-3"},{"id":"1-1-1-3:9","text":"E","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1-1-1-3"},{"id":"1-1-2","text":"Electronic City","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1-1"},{"id":"1-1-2-2","text":"TCS       ","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1-1-2"},{"id":"1-1-2-2-4","text":"C","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1-1-2-2"},{"id":"1-1-2-2-5","text":"E","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1-1-2-2"},{"id":"1-1-2-2-6","text":"F","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1-1-2-2"},{"id":"1-1-2-2-7","text":"G","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1-1-2-2"},{"id":"1-1-3","text":"WhiteField","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1-1"},{"id":"1-1-3-4","text":"IBM       ","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1-1-3"},{"id":"1-1-3-4-10","text":"F","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1-1-3-4"},{"id":"1-1-4","text":"Marathahally","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1-1"},{"id":"1-1-4-5","text":"Wipro     ","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1-1-4"},{"id":"1-1-4-5-11","text":"G","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1-1-4-5"},{"id":"1-2","text":"Chennai","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1"},{"id":"1-2-5","text":"sholinganallur","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1-2"},{"id":"1-2-6","text":"Tiruvanmiyur","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"1-2"},{"id":"2","text":"UK","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"#"},{"id":"2-3","text":"London","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"2"},{"id":"3","text":"US","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"#"},{"id":"3-4","text":"Texas","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"3"},{"id":"3-5","text":"Washington","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"3"},{"id":"3-6","text":"California","state":{"opened":false},"parent":"3"}]

$.jstree.defaults.core = {};
var currentlevel;
$('#tree')
    .on('changed.jstree', function (event, data) {
        if( data.action == 'select_node'){ 
            $('#tree').find('li').removeClass('disabled_node');
console.log('select '+ data.node.text);           

            currentlevel = parseInt( $('#'+data.node.id).attr('aria-level') );
            $('#tree').find('li').each( function() {
                if($(this).attr('aria-level') > currentlevel) {
                    $(this).addClass('disabled_node');
                    // remove checks from levels below
                    $('#tree').jstree('deselect_node', '#'+this.id);

                } else if($(this).attr('aria-level') < currentlevel) {
                    // remove checks from levels above
                    $('#tree').jstree('deselect_node', '#'+this.id);
                }  
            });
        }

        if( data.action == 'deselect_node' && data.event && data.event.type === 'click'){    
            // if have other checked nodes at same level - do not enable children
            if ( $('#tree').find('li:not(#'+data.node.id+')[aria-level="'+currentlevel+'"][aria-selected="true"]').length>0 ) {
                return;
            }

            $('#tree').find('li').each( function() {
                if($(this).attr('aria-level') > currentlevel) {
                    $(this).removeClass('disabled_node');   
                }
            }); 
        }
    })
    .on('open_node.jstree', function(event, obj ) {
        $('#'+obj.node.id).find('li').each( function() {           
            if($(this).attr('aria-level') > currentlevel) {
                $(this).addClass('disabled_node');   
            }
        }); 
    })
    .jstree({
    "core" : {
        "data" : data,
        "multiple": true,
        "themes": {
            "url": true,
            "icons": true
        }
    },
    "checkbox" : {
      "three_state" : false
    },
  "conditionalselect" : function (node, event) {
      return !$('#'+node.id).hasClass('disabled_node');
    },
    "plugins" : [ "checkbox","conditionalselect" ]
 });
```

Thanks to [nikolay-ermakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4531787/nikolay-ermakov)

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers\fiddles listed above works in most scenarios but one. All the above scenarios works fine as long as all the nodes are expanded (**becuase once you collapse a node, it is removed from the dom**).

Assume you select a node at level three and then you collapse the node at level three and then you select a node at level 1, it system does not un-select level 3 node (as it was removed from dom when node was collapsed) and nodes at level 1 and 3 remains selected.

To fix the issue, I am sending the node an additional field in the JSON call `level` which tells you about the current level of the node.

```
var myTree = $('#tree');

myTree .on('changed.jstree', function(event, data) {
      mee.disableTreeNodesAtOtherLevels(event,data,myTree );
    });

disableTreeNodesAtOtherLevels(event,data, tree){
    var currentlevel = parseInt($('#' + data.node.id).attr('aria-level'));
    var selectedNodes = tree.jstree(true).get_selected(true);
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedNodes.length; i++) {
      if(selectedNodes[i].original.level !== currentlevel){
         tree.jstree(true).deselect_node(selectedNodes[i], true);
      }
    }
  }
```

All this works based on assumption the data you are binding to tree is having a property called level